# Azure Storage blob using custom domain is not resolving while subdomain worked - how to set up host records?

Tags: dns, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

Yesterday I had successfully setup a custom subdomain in Azure storage.
I had set up assets.iprobesolutions.com to point to iprobesolutions.blob.core.windows.net. This is a screenshot of my host records CNAME set up: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ndfmn5dd7m48aqg/Screenshot%202016-05-30%2019.36.11.png?dl=0. As I said, this was working fine.

Today I decided instead to have iprobesolutions.com point to iprobesolutions.blob.core.windows.net and got as far as Azure accepting the domain using the indirect CNAME validation.

However while http://iprobesolutions.blob.core.windows.net/docs/installation-note-en-us-bosch-dicentis-wireless-installation-set-up.pdf is resolving, when I try the following it does not resolve http://iprobesolutions.com/docs/installation-note-en-us-bosch-dicentis-wireless-installation-set-up.pdf and I get error "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable".

These are my host record setups for iprobesolutions.com: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xqw2d9k3gj6mnjs/Screenshot%202016-05-30%2021.30.22.png?dl=0

I've tried many combinations for a few hours and can't get it to work....

Does anyone have an idea what I'm missing ? iprobesolutions.com is hosted in azure app service. Can't I use the same domain for both hosting and blob storage ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't map a domain to both a web app (running in the app service) and storage. Also, you can't CNAME the root domain (so you can't map iprobesolutions.com to blob storage).

You should be able to map www.iprobesolutions.com to blob storage, though. But realize if you do this, anybody who types in www.iprobesolutions.com will not be taken to your web app, which is the expected behavior. You might want to reconsider that course of action, and use storage.iprobesolutions.com or something like that instead.

Comment: I currently have the Azure Storage account mapped to www.iprobesolutions.com as well as the Azure App Service mapped to www.iprobesolutions.com and iprobesolutions.com per this screenshot https://www.dropbox.com/s/osqm50ukojuk5f6/Screenshot%202016-06-01%2019.57.01.png?dl=0. However when I type in the www, version it takes me to the web app... and not to the storage. Maybe it's because of url rewrite rules to redirect www.iprobesolutions.com to iprobesolutions.com. Based on your answer don't map the domain to both I'll use assets.iprobesolutions.com to redirect to iprobesolutions.com/docs/..Tx!

Comment: @tamra thinking about the matter further, if I'm required to use a subdomain such as assets.iprobesolutions.com/docs/test.txt to display in lieu of the blob url and redirect it to iprobesolutions.com/docs/test.txt, in order to set up a 301 redirect am I not supposed to have the subdomain hosted so iis server can be set to redirect from subdomain to domain? If I'm not supposed to map my subdomain to both an Azure App Service and a storage account, then where and how am I supposed to have the web.config tell the subdomain folder to redirect if there is no host for it ? Am I missing something ?

Comment: Just found this potential lead to redirecting a subdomain  1) create an Create an A Record for the subdomain and point it at the IP address for the website and 2) in IIS  select the primary domain and add a binding for the subdomain source: https://forums.iis.net/t/1216172.aspx ...hopefully this is the right solution :) I'll try it...

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem is that you must include the subdomain in the CNAME record.

From https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-custom-domain-name/:

> A CNAME record is a DNS feature that maps a source domain to a
>   destination domain. In this case, the source domain is your custom
>   domain and subdomain--note that the subdomain is always required.

Can you try your second mapping with a subdomain and see if that works?

Comment: I changed the azure custom domain to www.iprobesolutions.com (instead of iprobesolutions.com). I set my host records as per this screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8w12he7p99bt1b6/Screenshot%202016-06-01%2016.26.34.png?dl=0  Then I tested http://iprobesolutions.blob.core.windows.net/docs/test.txt which works fine per this screenshot https://www.dropbox.com/s/mv4ye6vg8rkvtba/Screenshot%202016-06-01%2016.35.20.png?dl=0  Next, I typed iprobesolutions.com/docs/test.txt however it is not found per https://www.dropbox.com/s/pp4nxyr5az6sgux/Screenshot%202016-06-01%2016.36.17.png?dl=0.

Comment: Can you try adding a CNAME entry that is just "www.iprobesolutions.com", mapped to "iprobesolutions.blob.core.windows.net"? It doesn't look like you have that, but that is what worked for your first subdomain, assets.iprobesolutions.com.

Comment: I did..see screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9yacc7qbk91ibr6/Screenshot%202016-06-01%2017.33.53.png?dl=0  What else could it be ? Since iprobesolutions.com is hosted in azure apps, is it maybe that it needs to be done via an url redirect instead ? See my more elaborate  question from yesterday per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37549395/how-to-have-azure-blob-storage-files-be-reachable-via-custom-domain-redirect-or

Comment: Is it possible that www.iprobesolutions.com is already mapped to iprobesolutions.com? If so, then you won't be able to map www to your blob storage endpoint. (It is possible to use www - I have it mapped as the subdomain for my own domain). We know that "assets" worked, so the issue may be with www.

Comment: I've asked a colleague to weigh in if that doesn't help.

Comment: I think the response below will help you. Also, we recommend that you delete all of your extra CNAME records. For storage, the only one you should need is the one that Robin notes below.

Comment: thank you for bringing in Robin to confirm! Now I'll tackle the IIS redirect from blob storage to the /docs and see if I can't get it to work as desired...I'll repost separately the IIS Question part 3 from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37549395/how-to-have-azure-blob-storage-files-be-reachable-via-custom-domain-redirect-or/37579913#37579913.

Comment: As posted also in the linked question, I've decided to wait on architecting the use of azure storage and our subdomain/domain with https until MS Server 2016 gets to GA with IIS 10.0. From the info I've located so far on trying this with IIS 8.0 it seems like it would be complicated and time consuming for me as a beginner in IIS/DNS to piece it together. So for now we'll put the docs folder as a subfolder of our site and continue with http until the technology and resources are available to make it an easier transition.